# If $(G,*)$ is a group and $a^{-1}=a, \forall a \in G$ then $G$ is abelian .

Tags: group-theory

If $(G,*)$ is a group and $a^{-1}=a, \forall a \in G$ then $G$ is abelian . Is it true or false and why?

Comment: **Hint:** $$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question has been downvoted because you didn't provide any information about how you got started and where you were stuck. You did get answers anyway - but next time please ask your question better. Note too that someone edited to improve the math formatting. Do that yourself next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. We have $abab=e$ then $ab=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ but $b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Take $a = xy$ for any $x,y \in G$

Comment: A brief remark of this kind is more appropriately offered as a Comment.

Comment: @hardmath You can say so and that's why I put the hint label in front. I usualy tend to do this when I believe a hint will do the job